# My IF statement is not working in windows form application

Tags: c#, if-statement, windows-forms-designer

I'm trying to create a gym membership with various radio buttons as different options. I want the user to be able to select the calculate button and the cost to appear in the text box but for some reason my if the statement is adding all the radio button costs together instead of just​ the one the user selects.

```c
private void calculatebutton_click(object sender, eventargs e)
{
int membershipcost = 0;

if (basicradiobutton.checked);
membershipcost += 10;

if (regularradiobutton.checked);
membershipcost += 15;

if (premiumradiobutton.checked);
membershipcost += 20;

membershipcosttxtbx.text = membershipcost.tostring();
```

Comment: You have a semicolon at the end of your if statements, that is essentially a no-op.

Comment: (Which makes this post "typographical error")

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the semicolons from your if statements or format your code like so:

```
private void calculatebutton_click(object sender, eventargs e)
{
    int membershipcost = 0;
    if (basicradiobutton.checked)
    {
        membershipcost += 10;
    }
    if (regularradiobutton.checked)
    {
        membershipcost += 15;
    }
    if (premiumradiobutton.checked)
    {
        membershipcost += 20;
    }
    membershipcosttxtbx.text = membershipcost.tostring();
}
```

Comment: Really weird, but my WF `if` statements do not work **without** semicolons

Answer (score 0):

Your C# is not written correctly. I suggest to use `{` & `}` to define a code block associated with the `if` condition. You can create a single line `if` statement, which I have included on the second `if`. Putting a `;` immediately after the `if(...)` will result in no action from the statement.

```
private void calculatebutton_click(object sender, eventargs e)
{
    int membershipcost = 0;

    if (basicradiobutton.checked)
    {
        membershipcost += 10;
    }

    if (regularradiobutton.checked) membershipcost += 15;

    if (premiumradiobutton.checked)
    {
        membershipcost += 20;
    }

    membershipcosttxtbx.text = membershipcost.tostring();
}
```